# The Advantages when we put AngularJS within Symfony web application

Tags: angularjs, symfony

Nowadays, is it necessary to integrate **AngularJS** within our web application built

with PHP ?

What are **the differences or advantages** between web **an application made with Symfony framework** and an application that represents a **combination of AngularJS and Symfony ?**

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask Questions like this don't belong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fundamental necessity to use AngularJS, or any other front-end framework. It solely depends on the requirements of your project. These are used when the front end must be responsive and/or must process input from the user and update parts of the page without the page being refreshed.